# how to avoid return of case sensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following code and its working just for case senestive values,
i want some how to overcome it that if the user use capital or lower case 
it will work the same,how should I do that ?

```
oAc.setFilterFunction(function(sValue, oItem) {
    debugger;

    var val = (oItem.getText().indexOf(sValue) != -1) || (oItem.getAdditionalText().indexOf(sValue) != -1);

    return val;

});
```

in sValue i got the value and val return true or false
in oItem.getText() I got the text to compare with like if I got in sValue = i
and the  oItem.getText() return index the method return true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way is to convert both values to lower/upper case before `indexOf()` operation

```
oAc.setFilterFunction(function (sValue, oItem) {
    debugger;
    sValue = sValue.toLowerCase();
    var val = (oItem.getText().toLowerCase().indexOf(sValue) != -1) || (oItem.getAdditionalText().toLowerCase().indexOf(sValue) != -1);

    return val;

});
```

---

Another solution is to use a regex to test the values instead of using `indexOf`

```
if (!RegExp.escape) {
    RegExp.escape = function (value) {
        return value.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
    };
}

oAc.setFilterFunction(function (sValue, oItem) {
    debugger;
    var regex = new RegExp(RegExp.escape(sValue), 'i');
    var val = regex.test(oItem.getText()) || regex.test(oItem.getAdditionalText());
    return val;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could convert the text to lower case.

```
oAc.setFilterFunction(function(sValue, oItem) {
    debugger;

    var val = (oItem.getText().toLowerCase().indexOf(sValue.toLowerCase()) != -1) || (oItem.getAdditionalText().toLowerCase().indexOf(sValue.toLowerCase()) != -1);

    return val;

})
```

Answer (score -2):

You can look into Java's built in function in the String class called toLowerCase() or toUpperCase()

More info here

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: it's about Javascript. not Java. Beside this, toLowerCase is the solution to go for.